# Count and full outer join on 2 tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I cant get this SQL query to work when trying to count the number of Savings accounts from a table labelled Account and displaying them by the Branch table field branchID.

I initially had tried this query:

```
SELECT Account.accType, Branch.bAddress.City
FROM Account
FULL OUTER JOIN Branch on Account.bID = Branch.bID
WHERE Account.acctype = 'Savings'
```

Which would return all instances of Savings accounts and Branches independently.

After doing some googling I have changed my Query to this:

```
SELECT Branch.bID AS "Branch ID", Branch.bAddress.City AS "Branch City",
COUNT(Account.accType)
FROM Account 
FULL OUTER JOIN Branch on Account.bID = Branch.bID
GROUP BY Branch.bID
```

Which gives the Error saying "not a GROUP BY expression".

Comment: `GROUP BY Branch.bID, Branch.bAddress.City` Oracle behaves differently than MySQL

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, it worked. How would I get it to display for Account.acctype = "savings"

Comment: @SammLaidlaw . . . I would suggest that you delete this question and ask another, unless Lukasz will write the solution in an answer.

Comment: @SammLaidlaw - just put the same `where` condition you originally had back into your second query, but as part of the `on` join condition i.e. with an an `and Account.acctype = 'Savings'` (before the `group by`).